# It's only displaying option correctly in database

Tags: php

I have a php code where it uses a a switch statement to find any of the values from the textbox and output the correct 'optionId' which matches the $selected_option which matches the value from the textbox.

The problem I have though is that lets say there are 4 questions, 3 questions with different options and 1 which has the same optionId as another question. When I insert them in the database it is suppose to look like below:

```
   Question               OptionId

    What is my gender     O17   //case '19'
    What is my name        O3    //case '5'
    What is my address     O17   //case '19'
    What is my age         O7    //case '9'
```

But instead it is showing only the latest OptionId for both questions like  below which is incorrect.

```
Question               OptionId

What is my gender      O7
What is my name        O7
What is my address     O7
What is my age         O7
```

So what I want to know is why is it displaying only the latest OptionId for all questions? Do I need to loop the switch statement or is there something wrong with the way I loop the $insertQuestion[] as that goes through each Question?

```
    $insertquestion = array();


        $options = $_POST['gridValues'];

        switch ($options){

            case "3": 
            $selected_option = "A-C";
            break;

            case "4": 
            $selected_option = "A-D";
            break;

            case "5": 
            $selected_option = "A-E";
            break;

            default:
            $selected_option = "";
            break;

        }      


  $optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = '". mysql_real_escape_string($selected_option)."')";

$optionrs = mysql_query($optionquery);
    while($optionrecord = mysql_fetch_array($optionrs)){
        $optionid[] = $optionrecord['OptionId'];
    }



foreach($_POST['questionText'] as $question)
{
    $insertquestion[] = "'". mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['id'] ) . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '') ."' ,'". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['num_questions'] ) ."','".  mysql_real_escape_string( $question ) ."','".  mysql_real_escape_string( $optionid[] ) ."'";
}

  $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, OptionId) 
  VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";



echo($questionsql)
```

UPDATE:

Below is the form code. How it works is the user types in a question in the textarea `('name='questionText')` and types in an option `(name='gridValues')` and then they append them two in a table row (table in the form which `id='qandatbl'`). This is the question 1. Then they do the same again for second question, then third and etc. Please look at this carefully, it is easy to follow :)

```
<script>

    function insertQuestion(form) {   

    var context = $('#optionAndAnswer');

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
    var $question = $("<td class='question'></td>");
    var $options = $("<td class='option'></td>");
    var $questionType = '';

    $('#questionTextArea').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                   .attr('value',$this.val())

    $question.append($questionText);

    });

    $('.gridTxt', context).each( function() {

     var $this = $(this);
     var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' />").attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
                     .attr('value',$this.val())

    $options.append($optionsText);
    $questionType = $this.val();

    });

    $tr.append($question);
    $tr.append($options);    
    $tbody.append($tr); 

    }

</script>


<form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post" >

<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Question:</td> 
    <td rowspan="3">
        <textarea id="questionTextArea" rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="optionAndAnswer" class="optionAndAnswer">
<tr class="option">
<td>Option Type:</td>
<td>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="gridValues" class="gridTxt maxRow" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="qandatbl" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="question">Question</th>
    <th class="option">Option Type</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

</form>
```

Comment: isn't it because you have only one optionID: `$optionid = $optionrecord['OptionId'];`?

Comment: how many results do you expect to get from `$optionquery`?

Comment: You need to get the correct opion ID for each question, so pretty much the whole code looks like it should be nested in the `foreach()` statement.

Comment: @Elen The amount of results is for every question, so for every question it would look for the correct optionId by looking through the case statement

Comment: @user1309180 at the moment your  `$optionquery` will give you only 1 results even if there are more. to get more you need to use while loop and store them in array.

Comment: @DavidGard i tried putting whole code in for each loop but still same problem

Comment: @Elen can you show an example on how to use the while loop for this example?

Comment: @user1309180 see my answer, if i correctly understood your problem, then we can take further steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as discussed - you have asked to show you how to apply loop:

```
$optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = '" 
         . mysql_real_escape_string($selected_option)."')";

    $optionrs = mysql_query($optionquery);
    while($optionrecord = mysql_fetch_array($optionrs)){
        $optionid[] = $optionrecord['OptionId'];
    }
```

your $optionid is then becomes array of all matched elements.

if you think i understood your problem correctly, then let me know so *we can work* on `UPDATE` query

---

UPDATE

```
$options[] = $_POST['gridValues'];
$i=0;

foreach($_POST['questionText'] as $question){

        switch ($options[$i]){
            case "3": 
            $selected_option = "A-C";
            break;
            case "4": 
            $selected_option = "A-D";
            break;
            case "5": 
            $selected_option = "A-E";
            break;
            default:
            $selected_option = "";
            break;
        }      
    $optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = '". mysql_real_escape_string($selected_option)."')";

    $optionrs = mysql_query($optionquery);
    $optionrecord = mysql_fetch_array($optionrs);
    $optionid = $optionrecord['OptionId'];

    $insertquestion[] = "'". mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['id'] ) . 
        ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '') ."' ,'". 
        mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['num_questions'] ) ."','".  
        mysql_real_escape_string( $question ) ."','". 
        mysql_real_escape_string( $optionid ) ."'";

    $i++;
}

$questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, OptionId) 
    VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";

    echo($questionsql);
```

Comment: I have updated code to include while loop you have given me. Problem is that when I do this, it doesn't ech INSERT VALUES statement when I echo $questionsql.

Comment: What I meant is look at this example: So lets says Question 1 has option 3 so look up case statement for case 3, case 3 equals A-C and by using $optionquery we find out A-C in database equals to OptionId 'O1'. For Question 2 lets say it has option 7 so look up case statement for case 7, case 7 equals A-G and by using $optionquery we find out A-G in database equals to OptionId 'O5'. So for each question it needs to look up all possible options and then find the one that matches the case statement.

Comment: I updated my code to include the coding from your answer but this hasn't worked as what this does is only insert 1 question only and that is the latest question added.

Comment: $options = $_POST['gridValues']; is holding the option number. So if this number is 3, then is the number the case statement tries to match. It is on the previous page from the database coding, shall I post the full code of this?

Comment: I have updated code above in my question to include whole form code. The thing is that for each question, the user is able to choose the option type then want. Thats why question 1 could have option 4, but question 2 could have option 7, it all depends what the user choose for an option for each question.

Comment: I am thinking just storing all the details qhich belongs for each question, so for question 1 it stores in the question, answer, option  etc that belongs to question 1. Then for question 2 store in the question, answer, option etc that belongs to question 2 and etc.

Comment: It is still displaying 1 question, but thank you for your efforts Elen, we will sort this out tommorow :)

Comment: i deleted all my previous comments, as it's getting too much. how many questions have been submitted? can you please paste here what you got echoed from above code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though it is inserting 07 each time as that is the last value in the array. You may need to loop through the $insertquestion array and run an insert each time.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, make sure you're using square brackets in your input names:

```
<textarea name="questionText[]" class="first_textarea">
<textarea name="questionText[]" class="second_textarea">
<textarea name="questionText[]" class="third_textarea">
```